# how can i write line by line in txt data?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, file

I try to write line by line data but. if i run my application. writng last text1 data in script.txt

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   System.IO.TextWriter tw;
   tw = new StreamWriter("C:/Script.txt");
   tw.WriteLine(textBox1.Text);
   tw.Close();
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by line by line data? what does the text data look like?

Comment: What's the problem? Do you have the right NTFS permissions?

Comment: You're only writing one thing... do you mean you want to *append* a line? or what?

Comment: need more clarification to what you need exactly

Answer (score 3):

If you need to append line but not replace all contents then pass "true" as second parameter to constructor of StreamWriter:

```
tw = new StreamWriter("C:/Script.txt", true);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that for what you want to achieve (assuming you want to append each line to the end of the file), using [`File.AppenAllLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383691.aspx) is the simplest way forward:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   File.AppendAllLines(@"C:\Script.txt", new[]{ textBox1.Text });
}
```

Alternatively, if you are not using .NET 4, you can use [`File.AppendAllText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143356.aspx) instead, adding a line feed to the end:

```
File.AppendAllText(@"C:\Script.txt", textBox1.Text + Environment.NewLine);
```

Answer (score 0):

OR

```
using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(fileName))
{
     sw.WriteLine(line);
}
```